# Prevent LINQ to SQL from returning child objects

Tags: sql, linq

I'm a LINQ to SQL newbie. I've got a simple DB with two tables. Events and Questions. Questions table has an EventId column that is a foreign key in to the Events table.

My query looks like this:

```
var questions = db.Questions.Where(u => u.EventId == 1);
```

the resulting object looks like this:

```
[{
    "QuestionId": 1,
    "Text": "",
    "EventId": 1,
    "Event": {
      "EventId": 1,
      "Title": "Event Name",
            "Questions": [ {
            "QuestionId": 1,
            "Text": "",
            "EventId": 1 } ]
     }
}]
```

LINQ to SQL appears to be adding the related event automatically, and also adding the related questions again to the Event. I had to turn tell JSON.Net to ignore the recursive references so that it would work, but I feel like my query is correct or I don't have the DB stuff configured correctly.

While there may be cases where getting the related object data is cool, I don't need it here. How do I adjust things so I just get the questions, like so:

```
[{
    "QuestionId": 1,
    "Text": "",
    "EventId": 1,
}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried enabling Lazy Loading?     You could also just ignore it in the data set, if it does no harm. 

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/12/LINQ-to-SQL-Lazy-Loading-and-Prefetching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Json.Net browses your object (including the virtual navigation attribute) while you still have you Database Context open, causing it to lazy load the references.

A simple fix would be to dispose of your Database context or detach the object before serializing your result.

Another fix would be to use a select to create a new detached object.

```
var questions = db.Questions.Where(u => u.EventId == 1).Select(u => new
    {
     QuestionId: u.QuestionId,
     Text: u.Text,
     EventId: u.EventId,
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!. I wasn't able to get the disposing of the context to work, but architecturally I decided to go with a select to a new object because it allows me more control over what's in the JSON.